# What is the correct way to use 'as adjective as' while comparing and/or contrasting two things?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

What is the correct syntax when you want to compare or contrast two things using 'as adjective as'?

Is it syntactically correct to say:
"You should be **as hurt** when someone in another country dies **as** you would when someone in your country does."

I am looking for a general syntax:
*--first part of the sentence--* **as adjective** *--first thing--* **as** --*thing to which it is compared/contrasted--*.

Is there a simpler way to present it?

Comment: Comparative/superlative - http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/comp.htm

Comment: It's called 'scalar comparison of equality'. The first "as" is called the 'comparative governor' and the second "as" heads the preposition phrase complement

Comment: Your analysis is good.  The form is 'as X as Y' with side material thrown in. "You should be as fresh (at dawn) as you are relaxed (at bedtime)."